# Div going over headerbar when scrolling

Tags: html, css, angular

Im trying to have a fixed headerbar and when you scroll, the content of the page need to go under the headerbar and not be displayed above. It works on mutliple pages, but it's not working for my calendar page.

This is what happens when you scroll:
[image]

On other pages, the content of the page will just go under the headerbar, but here it won't work.
This my html and css for the header-bar:

```
<div class="headerclass">
  <nz-header class="header-bar">
    <a
      role="button"
      (click)="toggleHidden()"
      [hidden]="false"
      class="home"
      id="menuButton"
    >
      <img
        src="../../../assets/images/baseline_menu_white_48dp.png"
        alt="Logo SafeSpace"
        widht="55px;"
        height="55px;"
        id="menu"
      />
    </a>
    <a role="button" routerLink="/Home" routerLinkActive="active">
      <img
        src="../../../assets/images/logo.png"
        alt="Logo SafeSpace"
        widht="55px;"
        height="55px;"
        id="logo"
      />
    </a>
    <img
      src="../../../assets/images/face-white-18dp.svg"
      alt="User logo"
      widht="45px;"
      height="45px;"
      id="face"
    />
    <img
      src="../../../assets/images/settings-white-18dp.svg"
      alt="Settings logo"
      widht="45px;"
      height="45px;"
      id="settings"
    />
    <a role="button" (click)="logout()" id="logout">
      <img
        src="../../../assets/images/exit_to_app-white-18dp.svg"
        alt="Logout logo"
        widht="45px;"
        height="45px;"
      />
    </a>
  </nz-header>
  <!--dropdownMenu-->
  <div class="menu">
    <ul nz-menu nzMode="inline" [hidden]="isHidden" class="menulist">
      <li nz-submenu nzTitle="Registreren">
        <ul>
          <li
            nz-menu-item
            role="button"
            id="RegisterChildMenu"
            (click)="registerChild()"
          >
            Registreer een kind
          </li>
          <li
            nz-menu-item
            role="button"
            id="RegisterSupervisorMenu"
            (click)="registerSupervisor()"
          >
            Registreer een begeleider
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li nz-menu-item role="button" id="CalendarMenu" (click)="calendar()">
        <span>Kalender</span>
      </li>
      <li nz-menu-item role="button" (click)="export()" id="export">
        <span>Exporteren</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
/* for smaller screen*/
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  #menuButton {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #logo {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* ANT DESIGN */
nz-header,
nz-footer {
  background: #7dbcea;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
}

.headerclass {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

As you see, I am using the z-index. I'm I using it wrong?
This is my code for the calendar:

```
<div class="calendar">
  <nz-calendar (nzPanelChange)="panelChange($event)" (nzSelectChange)="selectChange($event)">
    <ul *nzDateCell="let date" class="events">
      <ng-container [ngSwitch]="date.getDate()">
        <li *ngFor="let day of appointments">
          <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="getDayFromDate(day.start)">
            <button nz-button nzType="text" 
            (click)="onAppointmentClicked(day.appointmentId)">{{day.child.userName}}</button>            
          </ng-container>
        </li>
      </ng-container>
    </ul>
  </nz-calendar>
  <nz-modal [(nzVisible)]="isVisible" nzTitle="Details afspraak" [nzFooter]="modalFooter" id="calendarDetail">                
    <app-appointment-details *ngIf="loadDetails" [appointment]="selectedAppointment"></app-appointment-details>
    <ng-template #modalFooter>
      <button nz-button nzType="primary" (click)="handleOk()">Ok</button>
    </ng-template>
 </nz-modal>
</div>
```

```
.calendar {
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  padding-top: 75px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

I'm using the ng-zorro library for this.
Does anybody know how I may fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You have put `calendar's` z-index greater than the `headerclass`

Let's try to understand what `z-index` do? Higher value of `z-index` means higher position.

So in your case,

```
   nz-header,
nz-footer {
  background: #7dbcea;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
}

.headerclass {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
 .calendar {
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  padding-top: 75px;
  z-index: 1;
  }
```

This would resolve your problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Need the property `z-index` that specify the level of the element. Try this:

```
#navbar {
  background-color:#990000;
  position:fixed;  
  z-index:1; /*Add this*/
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  line-height:50px;
  top:0px;
}
```